# How write a greater and less than query in grails using MongoDb

Tags: mysql, mongodb, hibernate, grails

Using Grails 2.3.7
DB - MongoDb

I'm trying to write a criteria query in grails for greater than and less than query.

Query :

```
def c = postprice.createCriteria()
        def results = c.list {
            le("post_to",diffDays.toLong())
            ge("post_From",diffDays.toLong())
            order("id", "desc")    
        }
```

DataBase values :-

> 1. FROM - 0   TO-2
> 2. FROM - 3   TO-8
> 3. FROM - 9   TO-30

diffDays value = 3

It doesn't give any result. result Size come zero.
Please Help. Thank you